# How do you remove an xdg-mime default association?

Tags: x11, gnome, window-managers, file-association, xdgutils

So `xdgmime default foo.desktop application/x-foo` will associate a mime type in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` like this:

```
[Default Applications]
...
application/x-foo=foo.desktop
```

**What is the "proper" way to remove the association?**

I just edited the file with `vim`, deleted the line, and it worked, but `xdg-mime` has install/uninstall for other purposes so is there a "right" way to remove the default?

Comment: Thanks for the question! For me it was in `~/.config/mimeapps.list` (Fedora 38)